# Is it possible to change text column to an integer-backed enum with no downtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord Model with a string column (let's call it `status`) which has 1 of 3 values. So it's a candidate for being an enum. I want to switch it to an integer-backed ActiveRecord enum with no downtime. Here's my recipe so far:

1. Add `status_id` to the table
2. Deploy code which writes to both `status` and `status_id`

   ```rb
   class Foo
     def status=(value)
       write_attribute(:status_id, value)
       write_attribute(:status, value)
     end
   end
   ```
3. Backfill rows which have NULL `status_id`
4. ???

I'd like to make the transition with no downtime.

I've considered various approaches involving the likes of `write_attribute` or `method_missing` but nothing gets me there. Even an approach which changes references to the column in the code itself back and forth will have downtime.

How can I make the transition without downtime?

Comment: Do you have foreign key constraints pointing to `status`?

Comment: Is your intention to get rid of the status column completely afterwards?

Comment: There are no foreign key constraints.
I want to get rid of the text status column, yes. But I also want the new integer column to be named "status".

Comment: I've discovered that GitLab has a toolkit for automagically setting up triggers and such in order to do no-downtime operations like this. I haven't yet thought through if it would be a part of a complete solution, because in this case a code change is required (defining the enum), so having that go live at the right time is still not solved https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/database/migration_helpers.rb